# CSS on hover effect that uses Psuedo element overlaps the main element

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Basically when I do a hover I want the effect to look like what is displayed below:

[image]

My site is [here](https://wordpress-493302-3130963.cloudwaysapps.com/)

Code is below *disregard the !important*:

```
    .cta-button-menu, .cta-button-menu::before {
        transition:all 0.3s linear !important;
        width: 120px !important;
        height: 50px !important;
        display: inline-flex !important;
        justify-content: center !important;
        align-items: center !important;
    }
    .cta-button-menu:hover {
        transform:rotateZ(-45deg) !important;
        background: #21B6CD !important;
        color: white !important;
    }   
    .cta-button-menu::before {
        content:"Book Now" !important;
        background-color:transparent !important;
        position:absolute !important;
        @include main-font($white, 16px !important, $font-bold !important);
      }
    .cta-button-menu:hover::before{
        transform: rotateZ(90deg) !important;
        background-color:#e72f54 !important;
        border:none !important;
    }
```

For some reason I cant get the blue button to overlap the red:before button. Can't figure it out

Comment: Please include a [mcve]. If I simply extract the HTML of the button element out, I don't see any issue with your CSS at all: https://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/hd8uofen/, meaning that there are other styles that are affecting it.

Comment: Have you tried to put `z-index: 999` on blue button? `.cta-button-menu:hover` on this i think....

Comment: Ok firstly I can´t provide html as its generated from a mega menu and secondly the example you generated is not what I need, I'm able to do what you did which is have the red button over the blue, I just can't get the blue over the red

Comment: @SinisaM yes i tried various combinations of z-index's and can't get it to work the way I want

Comment: have you tried to exchange the colors in `.cta-button-menu:hover` set `background: #e72f54` and `.cta-button-menu:hover::before` `background-color:#21B6CD` ?

Answer (score 1):

Exchange the colors in `.cta-button-menu:hover` set `background: #e72f54` and `.cta-button-menu:hover::before` set `background-color:#21B6CD`. And also change the degrees. Hope this works on your side

```css
ul {
margin-top: 60px;
}
.cta-button-menu,
    .cta-button-menu::before {
      transition: all 0.3s linear !important;
      width: 120px !important;
      height: 50px !important;
      display: inline-flex !important;
      justify-content: center !important;
      align-items: center !important;
    }

    .cta-button-menu:hover {
      transform: rotateZ(45deg) !important;
      background: #e72f54 !important;
      color: white !important;

    }

    .cta-button-menu::before {
      content: "Book Now" !important;
      background-color: transparent !important;
      position: absolute !important;
      @include main-font($white, 16px !important, $font-bold !important);
    }

    .cta-button-menu:hover::before {
      transform: rotateZ(-90deg) !important;
      background-color: #21B6CD !important;
      border: none !important;

    }
```

```html
<ul>
<li class="cta-button-menu"><a class="mega-menu-link" tabindex="0">Book Now</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using a `transform` and `transform-style`.

```
.cta-button-menu {
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.cta-button-menu:hover::before {
  transform: rotateZ(90deg) translateZ(-1px);
}
```

https://codepen.io/James0r/pen/GRBqjOb

Not supported in IE11.

Answer (score 0):

@SinsiaM you got me thinking a bit on this and I just changed the following:

```
    .cta-button-menu:hover {
        transform:rotateZ(45deg) !important;
        background-color:#e72f54 !important;
        color: white !important;
    }   
    .cta-button-menu:hover::before{
        transform: rotateZ(270deg) !important;
        background: #21B6CD !important;
        z-index: 1;
        border:none !important;
    }
```